# compare column one between two files and append the data from one file to another

Tags: awk

I am having two files **fileone** and **filetwo** as below:

```
fileone:
    a   0   0
    b   4   3
    c   3   2
    f   3   2
filetwo:
    a   3
    b   2
    f   2
```

If column1 from **fileone** and column1 from **filetwo** are matcing then I need to append the **column2** from **filetwo** to **fileone** as below:

```
Output:

    a   0   0   3
    b   4   3   2
    c   3   2
    f   3   2   2
```

I tried this but not getting the desired output:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "These reports are based on this run:" ; pwd
echo " " ;
awk -F, 'FNR==NR {a[$1]; next}; $1 in a' fileone filetwo
```

Comment: There is the `join` command that does exactly this: `join -a 1 -a 2 -e '' file1 file2`. For details on what this means, see `man join`

Comment: You're setting the FS to `,` but you don't have any `,`s in your input or output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close, Input_file sequence you passed should be changed :) along with NOT having field separator as `,` in your attempt.

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} {print $0,($1 in a?a[$1]:"")}' Input_file2  Input_file1
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                              ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{                           ##Checking condition which will be TRUE when Input_file2 is being read.
  a[$1]=$2                         ##Creating array a with index of $1 and value of $2 here.
  next                             ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  print $0,($1 in a?a[$1]:"")      ##Printing current line and checking if 1st field is there in a then print a[$1] or print NULL.
}
' Input_file2  Input_file1         ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

OR in case you want to get good looking alignment try `column`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} {print $0,($1 in a?a[$1]:"")}' file2  file1 | 
column -t
```